# Is there any published research on pedagogy of the semester vs trimester systems at the high school or university levels?

Tags: teaching, university, reference-request

I have found some anecdotal evidence, but I only found one systematic study by [Bair and Bair](http://www.jstor.org/stable/41406184?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

I'm specifically interested in the answers for Mathematics, Physics, and Engineering disciplines.

Comment: Could you provide details on the bibliographical search you have already carried out in relation to your question? Sounds like it would be a great question for a subject librarian in an education department.

Comment: McCreary, Jason, and Charles Hausman. "Differences in Student Outcomes between Block, Semester, and Trimester Schedules." (2001).

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.trimesters.org/SemVsTrimester.pdf

Comment: @user65587 It's not like there's a reason to assume that a document pulled from `trimesters.org` is going to have a bias one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about semester vs. trimester, but I have seen research showing that taking 2 semesters to learn Calculus I prepares students more completely, and makes them more resistant to leaving STEM majors:

Nelson, M. (2014, September). Oral Reviews: Retaining STEM Majors. In Innovations in Teaching & Learning Conference Proceedings (Vol. 6).

and
Nelson, M. A. (2010). Oral assessments: Improving retention, grades, and understanding. PRIMUS, 21(1), 47-61.

Comment: Two semesters vs one semester? Or two semesters vs two quarters? Three quarters? Your control group / comparison group is unclear.